# Remove "Chapter" prefix from ToC in amsbook class

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I am struggling to make a small change to the Table of Contents of my `amsbook` document in `LyX`.
Basically, I just want to change the ToC to say

```
1.   Something
```

instead of

```
Chapter 1.  Something
```

as it does currently (so, basically get rid of the Chapter bit).
I would like to keep the Appendix name in the ToC, probably.

I've already redefined `\@makechapterhead` to fix the chapter headings.

I've tried to cut down my LyX document to something minimal which builds. There's probably more which could be taken out, but hopefully it's brief enough to understand!

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,british,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%Change (numbered) chapter style to something more plain
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\global\topskip 2.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xxpt}{22}\bfseries%\centering
    \thechapter\enspace\enspace\enspace #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }

% Change (un-numbered) chapter style to something more plain
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\global\topskip 2.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xxpt}{22}\bfseries%\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }

% Make chapter lines of TOC be BOLD
\def\l@chapter{\@tocline{0}{8pt plus1pt}{0pt}{}{\bfseries}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Something}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
Some text

\chapter{Something Else}
\section{Another Section}

\appendix

\chapter{Something in Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro responsible for inserting "Chapter" is `\tocchapter`; just redefine it to

```
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#2.\quad}}#3%
}
```

The original definition has `\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad`; `#1` and in the `.toc` file you find

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{Something}}{2}
```

so you can see that `Chapter` is argument `#1` to `\tocchapter`.

A good place for the redefinition is just above where you redefine `\l@chapter`.